# UINavigationBar shadow redraw on orientation change

Tags: ios, uikit

I have added a drop shadow to the navigation bar view's layer using the shadowColor, shadowOffset, etc. properties.

The shadow looks great but when I change the device orientation (portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait), I can visibly see the shadow re-drawing.

It only happens for a split second but it's noticeable. I have set the shadowPath property on the layer, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: i'm setting the shadow on the navigation bar view's layer using the shadowColor, shadowOffset, etc. properties. i.e. i'm not drawing it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

When I implemented my own vanilla view which implemented layoutSubviews and added my own UINavigationBar to it, pushing and popping my UINavigationItems my self, this solved the glitch on rotation.